# Exclude specific row in SQL

Tags: sql, db2

There is a query which returns table like below:

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 40 |

I want to exclude rows where TYPE is 40. but there isn't type 30 with same ID. In above table you can see with `ID=1` there is type 30 and 40, I don't want to touch this, but with `ID=2` there isn't type 30, so I want remove type 40, too. The result I want is:

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |

I can do it while fetching these values, but let's say I don't want to do it and I need to exclude that row after getting that result with subquery or maybe some better way.

Comment: You will do better to show both original sample data of your table(s) and the expected result and explain the entire logic behind. You write about very specific values (30,40), but it's unclear if you require a query with hard coded values or a more general/dynamic query.

Comment: Let's say this is a query:
"Select id, type from customers where status = 10 order by id"
You are right my question is not specific, but I don't want to make a change to base query, I need better ideas to eliminate that rows after getting result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE with a Window function. e.g. with this sample data

```
declare @demo table (ID int, [TYPE] int);
insert into @demo (ID, [TYPE]) values
(1,10),(1,20),(1,30),(1,40)
,(2,10),(2,20),(2,40);
```

The following query would return your expected results:

```
;;;;with cte as
(
    select ID,[TYPE], LAG([TYPE],1,[TYPE] - 10) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, [TYPE]) as prev
    from @demo
)
select ID, [TYPE]
from cte
where prev = [TYPE] - 10;
```

It's worth noting that if ID = 1, TYPE = 20 was missing then the subsequent rows would be excluded as well - i.e. this does not honour your specific 'if 30 is missing then exclude 40 too'. If you want that then you will need an additional AND clause in the where-clause. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

In this case I've used a CTE for the first part of the query, you could just as easily use a table variable, a temporary table or a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

For each row: `FLAG` <> 0, if there is a row with `TYPE` = 30 in a group with the same `ID`, and 0 otherwise.

```
WITH T (ID, TYPE) AS
(
VALUES 
  (1, 10)
, (1, 20)
, (1, 30)
, (1, 40)
, (2, 10)
, (2, 20)
, (2, 40)
)
SELECT ID, TYPE
FROM
(
SELECT 
  *
, COUNT (DECODE (TYPE, 30, 1)) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS FLAG
FROM T
)
WHERE NOT (TYPE = 40 AND FLAG = 0)
ORDER BY ID, TYPE
```

| ID | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 1 | 40 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |

Answer (score 0):

**[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H_luk4KK)**

You can use this query:

```
with grouped_values as (
  select id, GROUP_CONCAT(value) as arr_of_values
  from data
  group by id
),
non_valid_ids as (
  select * 
  from grouped_values
  where not find_in_set(30, arr_of_values) or not find_in_set(40, arr_of_values)
)
select data.*
from data
left join non_valid_ids nvi on nvi.id = data.id
where not (nvi.id is not null and data.value = 40);
```

Details:

1. Firstly, group `value`'s into array by `id` column (`grouped_values`  CTE)
2. Then filter those ids which do not have both values 30 and 40 (`non_valid_ids` CTE).
3. Finally, in the final query filter all valid data joining `data` and `non_valid_ids` and filtering those rows which are valid indeed via `not (nvi.id is not null and data.value = 40)` condition.